# How to enable the disabled tabs in bootstrap wizard

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap wizard in my website. On page load I wanted to disable all the nav tabs and when i click the next button that nav tab should be enabled.

I used this below code to enable and disable the nav tabs, the nav tabs are disabled but on click on tabs it showing the container of that particular tab

```
// Disable step
$('#disable-step').on('click', function() {
    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('disable', $('#stepid').val());
});
// Enable step
$('#enable-step').on('click', function() {
    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('enable', $('#stepid').val());
});
```

I used this code to disable the nav tabs, it is worked but once I clicked next button it can not go to back step

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        alert('on tab click disabled');
        return false;
    }
});
```

I wanted to do enable the nav tab of that particular next button.

Comment: can we have a fiddle demo for a better idea.

Comment: $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) { if(prevIndex > currentIndex){ return true;} else{ return false; } }});